# How to make controller with changings parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have request like this:

```
GET: /accounts/filter/?status_neq=test&birth_lt=643972596&country_eq=Endgland&limit=5&query_id=110
```

So, the next request coud be like this:

```
GET: /accounts/filter/?status_eq=test&birth_gt=643972596&country_year=1970&limit=5&query_id=110
```

And so on.

I create simple controller, but i do not know how to do this so that you accept such variable input parameters in the controller:

```
[ResponseCache(CacheProfileName = "FilterCache", Duration = 10, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.Any, NoStore = false)]
[Route("/accounts/filter/")]
[ApiController]
public class FilterController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET: api/Filter
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET: api/Filter/5
    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "Get")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST: api/Filter
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody] string value)
    {
    }

    // PUT: api/Filter/5
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody] string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE: api/ApiWithActions/5
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need to pass it as a list of parameters to your action method inside the controller or you can also use the [FromQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2#customize-model-binding-behavior-with-attributes) attribute.**

```
[ResponseCache(CacheProfileName = "FilterCache", Duration = 10, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.Any, NoStore = false)]
[Route("/accounts/filter/")]
[ApiController]
public class FilterController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET: /accounts/filter/?status_eq=test&birth_gt=643972596&country_year=1970&limit=5&query_id=110
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get(string status_eq, long birth_gt, int country_year, int limit, int query_id)
)
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

or

```
[ResponseCache(CacheProfileName = "FilterCache", Duration = 10, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.Any, NoStore = false)]
[Route("/accounts/filter/")]
[ApiController]
public class FilterController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET: /accounts/filter/?status_eq=test&birth_gt=643972596&country_year=1970&limit=5&query_id=110
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get([FromQuery] string status_eq, [FromQuery] long birth_gt, [FromQuery] int country_year, [FromQuery] int limit, [FromQuery] int query_id)
)
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean: shoud i create multiply parameters for all available sets of arguments? ex: country_eq, country_lt ,county_year and so on?

Comment: you can create overloads of your action methods to handle different kinds of query strings which you want, in which appropriate model binding will happen from the query strings.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should define different parameters for different query string.

If you do not want to specify the parameters in controller action, you could try `HttpContext.Request.Query` to get all query string.

```
public ActionResult MultipleParameters()
{
    var parameters = HttpContext.Request.Query;
    return Ok(parameters.ToList());
}
```